# android parse special format txt file

Tags: android, algorithm, parsing, readfile, country

I need a help to parse a special format file in Android.

The File content is pasted as follow.

????en
AL|Albania
DZ|Algeria
AD|Andorra
AO|Angola
AO_Bengo|Bengo
AO_Benguela|Benguela
AO_Bie|Bie
AO_Cabinda|Cabinda
AO_Cuando Cubango|Cuando Cubango
AO_Cuanza Norte|Cuanza Norte
AO_Cuanza Sul|Cuanza Sul
AO_Cunene|Cunene
AO_Huambo|Huambo
AO_Huila|Huila
AO_Luanda|Luanda
????en

The file content startwith character "????" I need parse country code and city code in a high way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Document is pretty chaotic... maybe you may use not parser, but something like this:

```
    ArrayList<String> countries = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> sities = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> codes= new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if(!line.contains("?")){
                String[] data = line.split(("\\|"); // this part maybe you should modify by yourself
                    codes.add(data[0]);
                    countries.add(data[0]);
                    cities.add(data[0]);
                }
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Hope it will be useful.

Comment: may be my question is not clear. But your answer is helpful for my question. Thx.